# unable to convert pdf to text using python script

Tags: python, glob

i want to convert all my .pdf files from a specific directory to .txt format using the command pdftotext... but i wanna do this using a python script...
my script contains:

```
import glob 
import os

fullPath = os.path.abspath("/home/eth1/Downloads")

for fileName in glob.glob(os.path.join(fullPath,'*.pdf')):
   fullFileName = os.path.join(fullPath, fileName)
   os.popen('pdftotext fullFileName')
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't open file 'fullFileName': No such file or directory.
```

Comment: `fullFileName = os.path.join(fullPath, fileName)` is redundant

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `fullFileName` literally to `os.popen`. You should do something like this instead (assuming that `fullFileName` does not have to be escaped):

```
os.popen('pdftotext %s' % fullFileName)
```

Also note that `os.popen` is considered deprecated, it's better to use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pdftotext", fullFileName])
```

It is also much safer as it handles spaces and special characters in `fullFileName` properly.

Comment: but one catch... it is converting only the first pdf... whereas i wanted to convert all from that dir

Comment: Well, of course place the whole stuff within your `for` loop where you originally had the `os.popen` call.

Comment: i tried that code as well... but still it is able to convert only the first file in the list....

Comment: Is it running `pdftotext` on each `pdf` file? You could tell by putting a `print` statement (or calling the `print()` function) inside the loop, or by adding a counter and printing its value at the end.

Comment: it is calling for all the files

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to

```
os.open('pdftotext {0}'.format(fullFileName))
```

This way the value of `fullFileName` will be passed, instead of the name.

Comment: but one catch... it is converting only the first pdf... whereas i wanted to convert all from that directory